# SSAS Tabular Model Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. While trying to add tables to the tabular model

Tags: ssas, ssas-2012, ssas-tabular

I'm trying to create my first SSAS Tabular model. I'm following the steps mentioned in following tutorial:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231690.aspx

While trying to load the tables to the model, I get the following error:

> Blockquote

"!! Relationship: dbo.DimCustomer[GeographyKey]->dbo.DimGeography[GeographyKey]

- Status: error
- Reason:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

!! Relationship: dbo.FactInternetSales[CustomerKey]->dbo.DimCustomer[CustomerKey]

- Status: error
- Reason:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

!! Relationship: dbo.FactInternetSales[OrderDateKey]->dbo.DimDate[DateKey]

- Status: error
- Reason:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

!! Relationship: dbo.FactInternetSales[DueDateKey]->dbo.DimDate[DateKey]

- Status: error
- Reason:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

!! Relationship: dbo.FactInternetSales[ShipDateKey]->dbo.DimDate[DateKey]

- Status: error
- Reason:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

!! Relationship: dbo.FactInternetSales[ProductKey]->dbo.DimProduct[ProductKey]

- Status: error
- Reason:Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

> Blockquote

What shall I do to get rid of this error message?

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and Visual Studio 2015 (SSDT).

Answer (score 1):

this is because SSAS can not process data.
I guess it's because of your impersonation setting in your connection.
check your connection setting and test it again.

Comment: I can see the tables listed and preview their data in existing connection and it's my local machine. It doesn't seem to be caused by impersonation setting. I've tried all the available options there. Issue persists.

Comment: I re-checked my connection in "Data Sources", hit "Save" and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your `model.bim` is closed when you're trying to deploy.  Change this to having the model open and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Same error but different solution - My case, I had two calculated fields with same name. Don't know how Tabular allowed it but removing old one resolved the issue. Hope this helps someone.